# Nginx location allow without termination

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi

I have the following rules:

```
location ~ /xmlrpc\.php {
    deny all;
}

location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi...
}
```

All works fine till I need to allow `xmlrpc.php` for some addresses.  Is there any way to allow `xmlrpc.php` without duplication rules for all others php? Probably something like to tell that this location is only for allow-deny not for real processing.

Update:  in fact I was aware of include variant.  Any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

move php settings to external file `php.conf`

```
fastcgi...
```

and include it in locations

```
location ~ /xmlrpc.php {
    deny all;
    include php.conf
}

location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    include php.conf
}
```

Comment: No, this is not what I was asking about.  I know how to allow.  I do not know how to avoid doubling the `fastcgi...` for every exception url that is partial allowed partial denied.  I need smth like `jump` or `continue`.

Answer (score 1):

You could configure your fastcgi in an extra file, like

```
# /etc/nginx/fcgi_php.conf
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
fastcgi_index index.php;
include fastcgi_params;
```

and use this file in your locations:

```
location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    include fcgi_php.conf
}

# allow / deny xmlrpc.php access
location ~ xmlrpc.php {
    allow 192.168.1.0/24;
    deny  all;

    include fcgi_php.conf;
}
```